# Incorrect values from operator casting with reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting

I'm trying to make a float wrapper (which will also do some magic stuff in the constructor).

However I find myself with quite odd errors.

```
class Foo {
public:
   Wrapper();

   operator const float& () const { return m_bar; }
   operator float& () { return m_bar; }

   const float& Get() const { return m_bar; }
   float& Get(){ return m_bar; }
private:
   float m_bar;
};
```

if I use Get() then I get the correct value but if I just use the cast operator then I get random values.

Isn't it possible cast a reference to a member?

Comment: It obviously is, but how do you use it? Any temporaries involved?

Comment: float bar = (float)foo; works for me fine using your class (i just made m_bar public to be able to set it)

Comment: Foo bar = 5; Add2dText(SomePos, white, "Bar: %f", bar);

Comment: @Raze: Try Foo bar = 5; Add2dText(SomePos, white, "Bar: %f", (float)bar); - that should work.

Comment: It types out text to the screen using the same syntax as printf() but with a 2D position and a color.

Comment: @Raze: What's the function declaration? And that's probably your problem right there, as Kornel explains.

Comment: @littleadv Ok that works, but why doesn't the compiler yell when I do something like this. CameraSpeed *= bar; instead just yield a undefined value?

Comment: @Raze: because the compiler is stupid. You're smart. You know that you're casting to vararg and not to float, and that you didn't write a casting operator for that. The compiler just pushes the object on stack as if the parameter requires Foo, and not float, because that's what it assumes. With varargs - the compiler has no idea what the actual type should be (although some tools do know how to do that, i.e.: lint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in your comment, you're passing the class to a vararg function (I guess it is vararg by the formating). The vararg passing does not work because it passes the address of the class and not a cast type (it doesn't know what it should cast it to when passing).

Using Get or an explicit cast is the only solution if you need to use varargs.

Comment: Okey, but do I need to use explicit casting for normal float operators too?

Comment: No, you need to avoid varargs functions, because they don't work with class objects.